# Получить номер порта ChromeDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, port

Как я могу получить id порта как переменную, для запущенного ChromeDriver.
При запуске теста в console отображается вывод:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233) on port 38169
Only local connections are allowed.
```

в данном случае id = 38169

Comment: а как вы его запускаете то?

Comment: пока просто локально один тест в IntelliJ Run test Ctrl+Shift+F10

Comment: драйвер как инициализируется в тесте? `webdriver.Chrome()` ?

Comment: в GebConfig 
    chrome {
        driver = { new ChromeDriver() }
    }
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "webdriver\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe")

Comment: У вас Java, на сколько понял? К сожалению, не подскажу, но в питоне порт здесь - driver.service.port. Может что-то подобное и у вас